# Using multiprocessing inside a function

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I want to take the working code from below and put it into a function.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def parameters(x,n):
    for i in x:
        yield (i,n)

def power(a):
    x, n = a
    
    return x**n

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = [i for i in range(1000)]
    p = parameters(p,2)
    agents = 4
    chunk = 10

    with mp.Pool(processes = agents) as pool:
        o = pool.map(power,p,chunksize = chunk)
    
    print(o)
```

So that I can call it whenever I want. I tried doing something like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def parameters(x,n):
    for i in x:
        yield (i,n)

def power(a):
    x, n = a
    
    return x**n

def calculate(s,n):
    p = [i for i in range(s)]
    p = parameters(p,n)

    agents = 4
    chunk = 10

    with mp.Pool(processes = agents) as pool:
        o = pool.map(power,p,chunksize = chunk)

    return o

print(calculate(1000,2))
```

However this does not work at all, It tells me That another process has started before one has ended. But the code above did work. Is there a way to properly take this code into a function? If not with this setup, then with what setup?

Comment: Your second code doesn't do anything except define functions.  How are you calling it?  Make a [mcve]

Comment: Where did you call your function `calclulate` actually? You would need to call it by `calculate(s,n)`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to protect code that should only run in the main process with `if __name__ == '__main__':`.  This code works:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def parameters(x,n):
    for i in x:
        yield (i,n)

def power(a):
    x, n = a
    return x**n

def calculate(s,n):
    p = [i for i in range(s)]
    p = parameters(p,n)

    agents = 4
    chunk = 10

    with mp.Pool(processes = agents) as pool:
        o = pool.map(power,p,chunksize = chunk)

    return o

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(calculate(1000,2))
```

Without the `if`, the following error is raised:

```
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Comment: I see. thank you, but what if i want to now run that through another function, does the "if" follow there as well?

Comment: @Miestrode Anything inside the `if` block runs only in the main process.